# Удаление коммитов из новой ветки

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Создал новую ветку, но в ней присутствуют все коммиты из master.
Как удалить все эти коммиты?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а зачем их удалять? Что вы хотите получить в итоге, какую задачу решаете?

Answer (score 4):

ветка (branch) в *git* — это всего лишь (плавающий) указатель на коммит.

создавая новую ветку, вы (по умолчанию) лишь дублируете указатель — он будет указывать на тот же самый коммит, что и текущая ветка.

при создании ветки, т.е., нового указателя, вы можете сразу задать, на какой коммит он будет указывать:

```
$ git branch имя-новой-ветки стартовая-точка
```

или (создать и сразу переключиться на новую ветку):

```
$ git checkout -b имя-новой-ветки стартовая-точка
```

---

более того — вы можете «передвинуть» уже созданный указатель:

```
$ git branch -f имя-существующей-ветки новая-стартовая-точка
```

---

а если «очень нужно» (оставляя за рамками целесообразность такого хода и целостность репозитория), то можно создать ветку «с нуля». т.е. первый коммит, который вы в неё сделаете, не будет иметь «предков». для этого служит опция `--orphan` команды `checkout`:

```
$ git checkout --orphan имя-новой-ветки
```

Answer (score 1):

Ветки в гит - способ разрабатывать что-то параллельно, с возможностью слить в основную ветку свои изменения.

Если вам нужна ветка без истории, значит вам нужна уже не ветка, а просто отдельный репозиторий.